# Set accessory mode fail on Nexus 4

Tags: android, accessory, nexus-4

I am trying to learn about Android open accessory, because I am a newbie to ARM programming. So I want to put everything up from bottom, use free open source tools and code.

1. Compiler: yagarto GNU ARM
2. NXP LPC1768 demo board: from a company named "waveshare"
3. USB driver example: NXP hostlite
4. Android phone is NEXUS 4, Android 4.2.2 version

The reference example NXP hostlite is small and clear. But I can not set accessory correctly in my devised code.

Description:

1. Inserting detection, and USB reset ---- OK
2. Read device descriptor   ---- OK
3. Set address to 1, change maximum-pakcet-size to 64  ----- OK
4. Read protocol, it returns 0x0002 . this means AOA v2 is supported. 
   ----OK
5. Write identifying string , 5 of them,  ----- OK
6. Set accessory mode. 
   I can see there is a port disconnect and then a port connect
   interrupt nitification in my Log print-out, ---- so seems this
   command is also OK
7. But when I try to read device descriptor now, it returns a
   Completion code  of 5 to me when TD_SETUP is sent out.  CC = = 5
   means a stall or no response. So I can't judge if the VID, PID is OK
   or not. ---- Fail

According to AOA protocol, after setting accessory mode, the device would re-enumerate itself.

So my question is: *What should I do for re-enumeration?*

1. Wait there until it finish itself; Do I need a delay?
2. Or reset the device and then read device descriptor again?(I don't
   think so, because the returned VID/PID are not correct.)
3. Or any suggestion you would like to share with me.

Answer (score 0):

I found: during reenumeration, a port reset is absolutely needed. Otherwise, it won't work!
There is no formal document to mention it. And a friend of mine who is familiar with USB told me a reset will bring the device to the same initial condition. But it's not in this application context. Now I can set to Android Accessory Mode successfully and connect with the NXP AOADemo apk.

Yeah! Next I will change the program on both device and host side. What I need is a little demo.

---

device descriptor before accessory mode:

00:12

01:01

02:00

03:02

04:00

05:00

06:00

07:40

08:**D1**

09:**18**

0A:**E1**

0B:**4E**

0C:28

0D:02

0E:01

0F:02

10:03

11:01

device descriptor after enter accessory mode:

00:12

01:01

02:00

03:02

04:00

05:00

06:00

07:40

08:**D1**

09:**18**

0A:**00**

0B:**2D**

0C:28

0D:02

0E:01

0F:02

10:03

11:01

VID 18D1, PID 2D00. I didn't turn on debug mode, so PID is 2D00, no problem. Not as what they said in another post.

======================================

Configuration descriptor:

-------Parse------------

09

02, configuration descriptor

20

00

01, 1 interface

01, 1 configuration

00

80

FA, Maximum current supply needed 500mA

---

09

04, interface descriptor

00

00

02, 2 endpoints

FF

FF

00

05

---

07

05, endpoint descriptor

81  in 1

02, bulk

40, maximum size 64 bytes

00

00

---

07

05, endpoint descriptor

02 out 2

02, bulk

40, maximum size 64 bytes

00

00

-------end of parse ------